# Adding styling to tablesorter

Tags: jquery, css, tablesorter, css-tables

See [this page](http://www.collegeanswerz.com/colleges), then click the "Table" tab.

I'm trying to add the triangles that indicate sorting, like this (http://datatables.net/blog/Twitter_Bootstrap_2), but I can't figure it out. The actual sorting is working, just not the styling.

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table headers w/ class `.tablesorter-header` are missing this CSS (change the url's of the images to your needs):

```
table#national_universities_table thead tr .tablesorter-header {
    background-image: url("images/bg.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

table#national_universities_table thead tr .tablesorter-headerAsc {
    background-image: url("images/asc.gif");
}

table#national_universities_table thead tr .tablesorter-headerDesc {
    background-image: url("images/desc.gif");
}
```

Comment: did you mean to have a space between table and #?

Comment: No space is needed between the table and its id.

Comment: I tried doing what you said, and the pointer cursor works, but the images still aren't there.  see the update to my site: http://www.collegeanswerz.com/colleges.

gimme 2 mins to finish updating

Comment: I just inspected all `.tablesorter-header`, and the CSS isn't being applied. Check your syntax for any errors.

Comment: it just finished updating (it might not have been updated when you checked).  could you check again?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34262/discussion-between-adam-zerner-and-eric-matthew-turano)